# Heroku ImportError: no module named

Tags: django, heroku, importerror, requirements.txt

I recently uninstalled django-markdown, and then installed django-markdown-app.  The site still runs fine locally.  But after pushing to Heroku, the site crashes with

`File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named django_markdown`

My `INSTALLED_APPS` setting contains `'django_markdown'`, which seems to trigger the error.

The requirements.txt file contains `django-markdown-app==0.8.6`.

When I do `heroku run pip freeze`, the result includes `django-markdown-app==0.8.6` as well.

Edit: Locally, after setting up a fresh virtualenv and running `pip install -r requirements.txt`, the app runs fine in the new virtualenv.